# Create a deeply nested object

Tags: javascript, recursion

I have the following object

```
const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Main",
    parent: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Computers",
    parent: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Components",
    parent: 2
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "RAM",
    parent: 3
  }
];
```

I would like it to return the following format

```
{
    "id": 4,
    "name": "RAM",
    "parent": {
        "id": 3,
        "name": "Components",
        "parent": {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Computers",
            "parent": {
                "id": 1,
                "name": "Main",
                "parent": null
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is the code I have for now

```
const recursiveBuild = (node) => {
  console.log(node);
  if (node.parent === null) {
    return node;
  }
  const parent = categories.find((cat) => cat.id === node.parent);
  node.parent = parent;
  return recursiveBuild(node.parent);
};

const item4 = categories.find((cat) => cat.id === 4);
const res = recursiveBuild(item4);
```

The end result is that I have traversed to the the beginning

```
{id: 1, name: 'Main', parent: null}
```

I believe I am very close, but still cant crack it yet. Appreciate if someone can help, thank u

Comment: I think your format is a bit weird and it looks like you are calling child objects parent objects. Like it makes to sense that "Main" object has a null parent, when clearly it has "Computers" as a parent object in the final structure. Furthermore, you could speed this up a lot by having the id:s as object keys in the first place, so you don't have to loop so much to find an object with specific id key-value.

Comment: Hi, The main object has null as its  parent because the object doesn't have any parent. The computer object has a parent Id of 1 because it was referring to the main object as its parent.

Comment: I mean yeah, it kind of makes sense from the "real world" point of view like "RAM"'s parent is "Components", but not like from a structural point of view, because "Components" is structurally a child object of "RAM" in the final object  I'm thinking it would make more sense [this way](https://pastebin.com/4zhg6syA)

Comment: Oh I get what u mean, yes yes, I am using that kind of data structure. Actually the reason why I needed it to have a parent  property is because when I want to select a particular category , I would like to know its ancestors, so that i can display it , very similar to ecommerce application. So in this case, if i select ram, i would like to have main->computers->components->ram.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed, you are very close.

You need to change this line:

```
return recursiveBuild(node.parent);
```

to these lines:

```
recursiveBuild(node.parent);
return node;
```

Here is the working snippet:

```js
const categories = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Main",
    parent: null
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Computers",
    parent: 1
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    name: "Components",
    parent: 2
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    name: "RAM",
    parent: 3
  }
];

const recursiveBuild = (node) => {
  
  if (node.parent === null) {
    return node;
  }
  const parent = categories.find((cat) => cat.id === node.parent);
  node.parent = parent;
  
  // return recursiveBuild(node.parent);
  recursiveBuild(node.parent);
  return node;
};

const item4 = categories.find((cat) => cat.id === 4);
const res = recursiveBuild(item4);

console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 1):

This works for me:

```js
const recursiveBuild = (node) => {
    /* console.log(node); */
    if (node.parent === null) {
        return node;
    }
    const parent = categories.find(cat => cat.id === node.parent);
    node.parent = recursiveBuild(parent);
    return node;
}
```

let me know if there are any issues